# What is the best solution for working together

Tags: php, svn, model-view-controller, project-management

I'm a web-designer and former coder. Recently I decided to start own project and hire different specialists (coders and designers) from different cities and countries. So, we have to find a solution that would let us work together, with one source.

For this purpose, I think of using SVN or something similar. Is this a good solution for collective working?

Maybe there is another, better ways to organize development?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"SVN or something similar" is not only a good solution, it's almost impossible to work together without some sort of version control.

So use SVN or use Git (check out if any of you have experience with either of them). 
Think about branching. Feature branches, release brances, etc. Read up on that, but DO use some sort of version control. It's essential

Then, you can check out other things like project management. You can use something like TRAC (although not in 1.0 release), or whatever you like to add some form of ticketing, milestones etc to your project.

Comment: Thank you Nanne. I think there will be only one branch. We'll work on a website that provides information services, filled up by users.

Comment: Don't say that too quickly. If you're adding a new feature, and at the same time some bugreport, small change or something like that should be done, you're allready dealing with 2 branches (live/release and dev branch). Keep it in mind ;)

Comment: SVN is tricky with things like web design because it's difficult to merge binary files such as images.

Comment: As far as i'm concerned that's a non-issue. If two persons both change an image, yes, then you'll have a problem, but that would be the case with any environment: merging images is never available, is it? Just pick one or merge manually. Has never been an issue for me...

Comment: +1 for the necessity of source control. Look into fengoffice.com for easy albeit basic project management

Answer (score 3):

Yes, version control is essential to keeping the coding portion straight.  SVN is good but there are definitely other options as well.

I would also suggest setting up a wiki that the team can organize, post designs, display schedules, etc.  This will definitely help on information/idea sharing.

Lastly, making sure everyone is able to instant message each other is very handy for team members in different locations.